# Tkinter,cx_freeze and PyCharm

Tags: tkinter, pycharm, cx-freeze

**I°)App description**

I made a program in python3. It's a program that work with a database in sql. I use the logiciel Py Charm community to do the application. I made a speciale folder with the command in python with all the sequence in sql in a folder Communicationddb
Every GI (graphic interface) it's a class and each GI have it's own file.
I use the following packages :

- ttkwidgets
- reportlab
- sqlite3
- tkinter
- Cx_freeze

**II°)problem**

I use cx_freeze to freeze my programm. You can see the setup after this paragraph. What my problem ? When I freeze the programm and I run it (just after the freeze) I have a lot alert message telling me :

- ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'tkinter'
- ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'ttkwidgets'
- ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'PIL'
- ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'reportlab'
- ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'Communicationddb'

I can resolve the problem. I copy the folder in tkinter,ttkwidgets .... in the lib folder. I can resolve the probleme and the app work but I want to understand how to solve it.

Here the setup that work (when I said it work I need to add manually the folder)

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
    icone = "icone_ip.ico"

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': ['atexit','reportlab','Communicationbdd']
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('BouclePrincipale.py', base="Win32GUI",icon=icone)
]

setup(name='ALCOIP',
      version='1.3',
      author="Dr MARCUCCI Charles",
      description='Outil de saisir des IP',
      executables=executables
      )
```

I try another code for the setup this one

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3

"""
Icone sous Windows: il faut:
=> un xxx.ico pour integration dans le exe, avec "icon=xxx.ico"
=> un xxx.png pour integration avec PyQt4 + demander la recopie avec includefiles.
"""

import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

#############################################################################
# preparation des options

# chemins de recherche des modules
# ajouter d'autres chemins (absolus) si necessaire: sys.path + ["chemin1", "chemin2"]
path = sys.path

# options d'inclusion/exclusion des modules
includes = ['atexit','reportlab','Communicationbdd']  # nommer les modules non trouves par cx_freeze
excludes = []
packages = []  # nommer les packages utilises

# copier les fichiers non-Python et/ou repertoires et leur contenu:
includefiles = []

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = 'Win32GUI'
    # includefiles += [...] : ajouter les recopies specifiques à Windows
elif sys.platform == "linux2":
    pass
    # includefiles += [...] : ajouter les recopies specifiques à Linux
else:
    pass
    # includefiles += [...] : cas du Mac OSX non traite ici

# pour que les bibliotheques binaires de /usr/lib soient recopiees aussi sous Linux
binpathincludes = []
if sys.platform == "linux2":
    binpathincludes += ["/usr/lib"]

# niveau d'optimisation pour la compilation en bytecodes
optimize = 0

# si True, n'affiche que les warning et les erreurs pendant le traitement cx_freeze
silent = True

# construction du dictionnaire des options
options = {
           "includes": includes,
           "excludes": excludes,
           "packages": packages,
           "include_files": includefiles
           }

# pour inclure sous Windows les dll system de Windows necessaires
if sys.platform == "win32":
    options["include_msvcr"] = True

#############################################################################
# preparation des cibles
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"  # pour application graphique sous Windows
    # base = "Console" # pour application en console sous Windows

icone = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    icone = "icone_ip.ico"

cible_1 = Executable(
    Executable('BouclePrincipale.py', base="Win32GUI",icon=icone)
)


#############################################################################
# creation du setup
setup(
    name="ALCOIp",
    version="1.00",
    description="Permet la saisi des IP",
    author="Dr MARCUCCI Charles",
    options={"build_exe": options},
    executables=[cible_1]
)
```

and i Have this error message :
**p = os.fspath(p)
Typeerror : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object not Executable**

I think it's link to py charm and how PyCharm work. I tried to remplace

```
includes = ['atexit','reportlab','Communicationbdd']
```

by

```
includes = ['atexit','venv/Lib/site-packages/reportlab','Communicationbdd']
```

but when I freeze the app can't run I have an error ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'reportlab'

**III°)The question**

how to deal with this error ? Do I need to change of integrated development environment ?

Thank you for your future answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer .... When I add a package it's only on PyCharm... I used pip to install on python and no just on PyCharm.
I lunch again my build and it work like a charm